# Multiple instances of the same nibLoaded custom view

Tags: cocoa-touch

I created a view with a Nib.
I want to add multiple instances of this subview but only the last one I add is displayed.

```
NSArray * nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SBFiveBarCountView"
                                                   owner:self
                                                 options:nil];

SBFiveBarCountView * fiveBarCount1 = (SBFiveBarCountView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
fiveBarCount1.frame = CGRectMake(22, 15, 16, 57);

SBFiveBarCountView * fiveBarCount2 = (SBFiveBarCountView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
fiveBarCount2.frame = CGRectMake(45, 15, 16, 57);

[self.view addSubview:fiveBarCount1];
[self.view addSubview:fiveBarCount2];
```

After I do that, only `fiveBarCount2` is actually added to the view

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the same object to two different variables.  That is, it's the object at location zero of the array no matter what you name it.

Since `loadNibNamed:` is the method that creates a new instance of the object (inside the array), you would need to call it a second time to get a different `SBFiveBarCountView` object.